# issue working with multi processing programming and open mp

Tags: multiprocessing, openmp

I am sending you a Toy program about multi-process programming.
the program is working well or not I can get 50% more performance.
 However if I enter # pragma parallel for
the program does not work anymore.
How can improve performace ?
How can I tell how many processes should I run to get
the best performance. For example, on 4-core or 8-core? :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>          
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X 100000

char matrix[8000*X] ;
volatile long barrier = 0 ;

unsigned long long start[] ={ 0         ,   1000*X+1    ,   2000*X+1    ,   3000*X+1    ,   4000*X+1    ,   5000*X+1,   7000*X+1 } ;
unsigned long long stop[]  ={ 1000*X    ,   2000*X      ,   3000*X      ,   4000*X      ,   5000*X      ,   6000*X  ,   8000*X   } ;

 void  init( void *arg1 ) 
 {
  long i ;
  const long s0 = start[(ULONG_PTR)arg1];
  const long s1 = stop[(ULONG_PTR)arg1];

  // #pragma omp parallel for <------ *** with pragma does not work ! ***
  for (i= s0 ; i< s1 ; i++ )
  {
    matrix[i] = 0 ;
  }
  ++barrier ;
 }

long main()
{
   register long i , ZZZ;
   clock_t tempo0 ;
   clock_t tempo1 ;

   // ********************************************************#1
    printf( "Now in the main() function.\n" );
    tempo0 = clock();
    for (ZZZ=0;ZZZ<100;ZZZ++)
    {
                  for ( i=0;i<8000*X;i++)
                    matrix[i] = 0 ;
    }
    tempo1 = clock();
    printf ( "\nsequenziale <%lf>\n" , (double) tempo1-tempo0 );

    //  return 0 ;
    // ******************************************************* #2
    tempo0 = clock();
    for (ZZZ=0;ZZZ<100;ZZZ++)
    {   
        barrier = 0 ;
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 0 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 1 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 2 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 3 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 4 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 5 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 6 );
        _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 7 );

        while ( barrier!=8) 
        ;
    }

    tempo1 = clock ();

    printf ( "\nthread <%lf>\n" , (double) tempo1-tempo0 );


}
```

thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would say that if you look at the work you put in the sequential and threaded section, it's not the same. So your time/performance comparison doesn't really make sense:

```
for (ZZZ=0;ZZZ<100;ZZZ++)
{
              for ( i=0;i<8000*X;i++)
                matrix[i] = 0 ;
}
```

you call 100 * the matrix init to 0
But in the threaded code, you initialize the matrix to 0 only 1 time!

**Now for your performance question.**

In fact you made several error in the way you want to scale and that's why at end it doesn't work when you uncomment the `#pragma omp parallel for`.

Imagine you have 8 core (1 thread per core) like in your sample. In your loop

```
for (ZZZ=0;ZZZ<100;ZZZ++)
{   
    barrier = 0 ;
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 0 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 1 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 2 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 3 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 4 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 5 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 6 );
    _beginthread( init, 0, (void*) 7 );

    while ( barrier!=8) 
    ;
}
```

8 thread are running, and now if you uncomment your OpenMp directive in the `init`function, you ask openMP to split the job of each init function over multiple (8) threads.

So now you have theoretically 8x8 thread running concurrently, but you only have 8 core. And Thats why it doesn't work. Performance will decrease because of all the tread context switch!

In fact to now answer your last question, " How can I tell how many processes should I run to get the best performance?",

1. we talk of thread, not of processes!
2. The ZZZ loop is your coarser granularity, so it's the loop where openMp can be use .
3. OpenMP will split your 100 iterations over your core 4, 8 16, etc... for free.

So i will rewrite your code like below:

```
tempo0 = clock();
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int z = 0 ; z < 8000*X ; z++)
{  
matrix[z] = 0;
}
tempo1 = clock ();
```

I only have 2 core but without OpenMP, it took 630 ticks, and only 452 with 2 core and it will automatically go down with more core.